# What does (String args []) mean?

Tags: java, mean, args

I have this in the `File.java`:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception_Exception {
    URL wsdlURL = CallSService.WSDL_LOCATION;
    if (args.length > 0) { 
        File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
        try {
            if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
            } else {
                wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

and I want to transfer this to a JSP file, so I do like that:

```
List<String> Search(String keyS){

if(keyS!=null){
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://ts.search.com/", "callSService");





String arg=??????????????;

URL wsdlURL = CallSService.WSDL_LOCATION;

File wsdlFile = new File(arg);
try {
    if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
        wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
    } else {
        wsdlURL = new URL(arg);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to replace the `args[0]` with `arg`. What does `(String args[])` mean? and how can I replace it ?

Comment: `Exception_Exception`? Moving along...

Comment: `String args[]` means you have an array named `args` of type `String`. What is your question?

Comment: what i can find in this array cuz i want to use his values

Answer (score 8):

`String args[]` is an array of Strings passed in from the command line.

So, if you started your app with `java MyApp arg1 arg2`

Then `args[]` would contain => `["arg1", "arg2"]`

Java will automatically split up arguments separated by spaces, which is how it knows how many arguments you passed in.

Comment: so how can i replace it in my eg ??

Comment: Not sure, as I'm not familiar with JSP specifically. Dave's answer seems to be the way to go, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this in a JSP :(

Don't put your functionality in a `main`, it's confusing: `public static void main` is conventionally a program's entry point, not a general purpose method. You may *use* it as one, but IMO it is misleading.

Instead, create an instance method you can call with the argument you want. It *could* be a `static` method, but this builds in some inflexibility making things more difficult to test. Embeddeding the code in a JSP also increases testing difficulty.

You'll need to use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` to get a file relative to the web app, unless you're providing an absolute path. If the file is "embedded" in the app (on the classpath) you'll want to use one of the `resourceAsStream` variants.

Comment: i'm usig jsp on a web service so i must do that i need just the values of args[0] to use in my method

Comment: Again: don't do this in a `main` function--create a normal function, pass in whatever arguments you need. I don't understand the issue.